# Google Analytics is not tracking app in foreign country

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have created an account and registered one iOS app in Google Analytics. When the app is tested in any device or simulator, it is tracked by google analytics. But when the app is used in the client location i.e Sweden, the tracking is not seen in the account. The client has used the app two days ago and the app details is not tracked, while the app when tested in any of my devices and simulator on the same day and next day is also tracked. And it is traced till date. Tracking is not reflected in the account when used by client in sweden.

The client is in a different country.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure that you have no filter selected (by country)?

Comment: No, I have not used any filters @hybridcattt